# Intercept and change function or method parameter value in error handler

Tags: php, error-handling, type-conversion

In [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php#83442) in the PHP manual, a user suggested a class which would implement an error handler capable to implement primitive type hinting for PHP.

I understand how that class operates, however, I would like to know if it is possible to bring it to another level: instead of only checking the argument value to see if it matches the "typehint", would it be possible to replace the value with another one if it does match, and how?

I was thinking about something along the line of:

```
if(gettype($funcValue) == $typeHint) {
  // here replace $funcValue, for example $funcValue = new Example($funcValue);
}
```

and then have the function call proceed with the new value?

I have searched the manual but found nothing which could allow me to "hook" in the parameters' values, but it could be there and I simply didn't find it.

Comment: Even the original idea sounds pretty bad, IMO. Abusing an error handler for type hinting is significant overhead. What you want is not possible I think without significant changes to PHP. The likes of runkit may help you here, but I still find it a bad idea.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/box/augmented_types

Comment: @deceze: I am not thinking of actually using it, I just wanted to see if it was possible, to play with the available tools to build a missing functionality.